# Flutter sqflite insert does not store full data fetched using http get

Tags: database, flutter, http, sqflite, flutter-getx

I'm new to Flutter

my app fetches json records from the http get method and stores the data to database.
very thing works fine json returns around 149 rows but app only inserts 101 row in the table there is no error or anything.

Firstly I thought that http only response with only 101 records but on testing http get prints all the 149 record but on insert to database it only insert's only 101 only
if I parse 80 or 90 records it all gets inserted but even 102 records only insert's 101
even tried Future Delay for 10s but it gets break at 101 and then waits till the delay in competed

APIProvider

`class ApiProvider {
  Future<List<NewProduct>?> getPro() async {
    Response response = await Dio().get(Info.productUrl);

    var res = response.data;
    print("PRODUCT LENGTH-" + res.length);
    (res as List).map((product) {
      DatabaseHelper.db.insertProduct(NewProduct.fromJson(product));
    }).toList();
  }
}`

Database Helper Class

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:models/newProductHome.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final _dbName = 'sawanDB.db';
  static final _dbVersion = 1;

  static Database? _database;
  static final DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper._();
  DatabaseHelper._();

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;

    _database = await _initiateDatabase();
    return _database!;
  }

  _initiateDatabase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, _dbName);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('DROP TABLE If EXISTS SA_PRO_MASTER');
    await db.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE SA_PRO_MASTER(
      sa_proid TEXT,
      sa_proname TEXT NOT NULL,
      sa_pcat TEXT NOT NULL,
      sa_pscat TEXT NOT NULL,
      sa_pbrand TEXT NOT NULL,
      sa_pro_code TEXT,
      sa_pro_capacity TEXT,
      sa_pro_status TEXT,
      sa_pro_mtitle TEXT,
      sa_pro_mkey TEXT,
      sa_pro_mdesc TEXT,
      sa_pro_date DATE,
      sa_pro_mainImg TEXT,
      sa_pro_ishome TEXT,
      sa_pro_desc TEXT,
      sa_pro_new TEXT,
      sa_pro_type TEXT
    )
    ''');
    print("DB TABLE SA_PRO_MASTER CREATED");

  }

  insertProduct(NewProduct listPro) async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db.insert('SA_PRO_MASTER', listPro.toJson());
    //print("INSERT RES - " + res.toString());
    return res;
  }

  Future<int> deleteAllProduct() async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM SA_PRO_MASTER');
    return res;
  }
}
```

Main where it loads Data while opening the app

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  DatabaseHelper.db.database;

  if (await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection) {
    print("INTERNERT AVAILABLE");

    DatabaseHelper.db.deleteAllProduct();
    await apiProvider.getAllProducts();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    runApp(MyApp());
  } else {
    print("NO INTERNET");
    runApp(NoConn());
  }

  //await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
}
```

Comment: Could you share some code on how you are inserting?

Comment: Are you sure it does not fail on parsing? Or other type of exception. Try to paste some example of the code, console output and data you try to insert.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.